# Adding angular momenta of 3 spin-(1/2) particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum

When adding three spin-$\frac{1}{2}$,

$|\frac{3}{2}\frac{3}{2}>$ = $\frac{1}{3} (uud + udu + duu)$

Now, I know that one of the $|\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2}>$ states is

$|\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2}>$ = $A(uud) + B(udu) + C(duu)$.

According to texts, I can choose A, B and C using orthogonality with other state and normalisation. But these only give me two equations

$A^2 + B^2 + C^2 = 1$

and

$A + B + C = 0 $

How do I find the third equation to get the values of A, B and C?

Comment: see this file: http://www-pnp.physics.ox.ac.uk/~mjohn/B3.pdf

Comment: @MojtabaGolshani This document also directly gives the coefficients without explaining how it got them.

Comment: Actually you can choose one of the coefficients freely. The two $|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\rangle$ functions given in the link are just "canonical examples", but any linear combination of them is also also a $|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\rangle$ function.